# Multiple arduino connections problem

Tags: arduino-mega, communication, python, ubuntu

I have 2 Arduino Mega 2560 connected via USB to my Ubuntu 18.04 machine. When I boot, one connects to `/dev/ttyACM0` and the other connects to `/dev/ttyACM1`.

Communication works perfectly. However, randomly on boot, the Arduino boards connect to the opposite port of what is coded into the script. I use Python 3.6 to communicate with the boards.

Is there any way to force these boards to always connect to the same port? Or is there a way for Python to detect the board that it's talking to?

Comment: https://majenko.co.uk/blog/making-your-boards-unique-linux

Comment: Thanks. Simpler solution found here. raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=216907